# Chrome Source Code Editing

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My problem is that I want to edit the html code of a webpage that I visit and then make chrome run the edited version of html. Using the edit HTML option I am able to edit the html but when i reload chrome gets the html from the website whereas I want to run the html that was edited. Also I can not store the html on my computer and then run because in that case it then resolves the links to my file system and not the website.

Comment: Upload the edited HTML to a web server or run a local web server. See https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-web-server-all-platforms/.

To resolve links, you can edit your hosts file to resolve to your new page.

Comment: Isnt there a way to run the edited html on chrome or any other browser.

Comment: I think there may be extensions for live editing code that you own, but if you are making arbitrary edits to a 3rd party site, this isn't possible.

Comment: I just want to make temporary edits on my local machine and then make the browser use that html. Could you tell me of some extension can't find any reliable one.